# Change raster range values from 0/100 to 1/100

Tags: r, raster, qgis

I have a raster layer ranging from 0 (minimum) to 100 (maximum) and I would like to change its values to range from 1 to 100. It is important that data do not change, basically I want to have the same raster but with a different range of values.

I can work both on R and QGIS.

Thanks everyone for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a simple example in R, where we have a raster with values ranging between 0 and 100, as we can see by the `min value` and `max value` fields:

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

r <- raster(matrix(c(0, 25, 100, 15, 0, 22, 86, 54, 67), nrow = 3))

r
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.3333333, 0.3333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 0, 100  (min, max)
```

To overwrite the 0 values with 1s, we can do

```r
r[][r[] == 0] <- 1
```

Resulting in

```r
r
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.3333333, 0.3333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could rescale the data using the `rescale` function in the `scales` package.

```
library(raster)
library(scales)

r <- raster(matrix(0:100))
plot(r)
```

[image: before]

```
r[] = rescale(r[], to=c(1,100))
plot(r)
```

[image: after]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
That worked perfectly, as I wished! Thanks again, I wish you a great day! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could accept the answer?

Comment: Ops, I am sorry I didn't know I had to do it! Thanks again